# Magento 2: How do I override the grid thumbnail preview copy?

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, grid, thumbnail

Using 2.1.3 - I've added a thumbnail image in a column to my admin grid - I like the built in preview ability, but want to change the copy underneath the image in the preview window. It looks like it's hardcoded into the `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/thumbnail.js` file:

```
....
preview: function (row) {
        var modalHtml = mageTemplate(
            thumbnailPreviewTemplate,
            {
                src: this.getOrigSrc(row), alt: this.getAlt(row), link: this.getLink(row),
                linkText: $.mage.__('Go to Details Page')
            }
        );
....
```

I've tried creating a copy of the thumbnail.js file in my own `Namespace_Module` directory (`app/code/Namespace/Module/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/thumbnail.js)`and pointed the grid element config to that directory, but don't see any changes:

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">file_path</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Photo</item>
            </item>
```

How can I override the hard coded copy in the thumbnail preview window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - figured it out - posting an answer to help anyone looking for the solution - the first line in `app/code/Namespace/Module/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/thumbnail.js` file defines an include of a relative path to `column.js`, so changing:

```
define([
'./column',
'jquery',
...
```

to:

```
define([
'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column',
'jquery',
```

and the page includes the overridden  file without error, and you can change the copy in the overridden file.